# Rails API - POST activation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to implement user accounts in a Rails API application.
I have the users logic working for registration and login but my problem is that the email link is a GET request, and the required action is POST. I can activate the URL via a POST request manually in Postman like this:

http://localhost:3000/users/confirm-request?token=b96be863aced91480a2a

How can this can be done via clicking a link in email?

My User controller:

```
    class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def create
    user = User.new(user_params)
    if user.save
      UserMailer.registration_confirmation(user).deliver
      render json: { status: 201 }, status: :created
    else
      render json: { errors: user.errors.full_messages }, status: :bad_request
    end
  end

  def confirm
    token = params[:token].to_s
    user = User.find_by(confirmation_token: token)

    if user.present? && user.confirmation_token_valid?
      user.mark_as_confirmed!
      render json: {status: 'User confirmed successfully'}, status: :ok
    else
      render json: {status: 'Invalid token'}, status: :not_found
    end
  end

  def login
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:email].to_s.downcase)

    if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
      if user.confirmed_at?
        auth_token = JsonWebToken.encode({user_id: user.id})
        render json: {auth_token: auth_token}, status: :ok
      else
        render json: {error: 'Email not verified' }, status: :unauthorized
      end
    else
      render json: {error: 'Invalid username / password'}, status: :unauthorized
    end
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end

end
```

My Routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :users, only: :create do
    collection do
      post 'confirm'
      post 'login'
    end
  end
```

registration_confirmation.text.erb:

```
Hi <%= @user.name %>,

Thanks for registering. To confirm your registration click the URL below.

<%= confirm_users_url(@user.confirmation_token) %>
```

Comment: AFAIK (as far as I know), you can't make links into POST as by default all links are GET. Now, you can however make links into POST but this is already done with JS. Having said that, emails don't really support JS (maybe some?), therefore it's best to just use GET request for this. To answer your question: you'll just need to change your routes.rb from `post 'confirm'` to `get 'confirm'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change code of `registration_confirmation.text.erb`

```
Hi <%= @user.name %>,

Thanks for registering. To confirm your registration click the URL below.

<%#= confirm_users_url(token: @user.confirmation_token) %>
<a href="/users/confirm?token=<%=@user.confirmation_token%>"></a>
```

Routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :users, only: :create do
    collection do
      get 'confirm'
      post 'login'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Sorry, that was there by mistake as a result of my experiments.

Comment: (If I wasn't clear) fixing this doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: No, the error I'm getting when using the link in the browser is : ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [GET] "/users/confirm"

Comment: I can't believe it was that simple, I was pretty sure I tried changing the route from post to get before. Thank you!